# how to show/hide list-box on onclick

Tags: javascript, listbox

Hi am having Main list box it contain a 3 value so if i have selected a first  value it have to show a text and then again i selected a second value it have to show listbox ..like wise it go i had tried but no result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.hidden 
{
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script>

function getValue()
{ 
  var x=document.getElementById("sel");
  var A=document.getElementById("a");
  var B=document.getElementById("b");
  var C=document.getElementById("c");

  for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) 
  {
     if(x.options[i].selected ==true)
     {
          if(x.options[i].value == "volvo")
           {
             A.style.display = 'block';
             B.style.display = 'none';
             C.style.display = 'none';
           }
         if(x.options[i].value == "Saab")
         {   
             A.style.display = 'block';
             B.style.display = 'none';
             C.style.display = 'none';
         }
         if(x.options[i].value == "Opel")
             {
             A.style.display = 'none';
             B.style.display = 'none';
             C.style.display = 'block';
             }


       }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="sel" onClick='getValue()'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>

 <div id="a" class="hidden">
    APPLE,Mango
</div>

<div id="b" class="hidden">
   <select>
   <option name="m">2</option>
   <option name="n">2</option>
   </select>
 </div>

 <div id="c" class="hidden">
 <select>
   <option name="e">3</option>
   <option name="f">3</option>
   </select>

   <select>
   <option name="i">4</option>
   <option name="j">4</option>
   </select>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't wise to use the "onclick" event on select menus. Try using "onChange" instead.

Answer (score 0):

use hidden attribute

a.hidden=false;

check this

```
<body>
<select id="sel">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>

<div id="a" hidden="hidden">
APPLE,Mango
</div>

<div id="b" hidden="hidden">
<select>
<option name="m">2</option>
<option name="n">2</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="c" hidden="hidden">
<select>
<option name="e">3</option>
<option name="f">3</option>
</select>

<select>
<option name="i">4</option>
<option name="j">4</option>
</select>

</div>


</body>
```

and in script side

```
var x=document.getElementById("sel");
var A=document.getElementById("a");
var B=document.getElementById("b");
var C=document.getElementById("c");

x.onchange=function()
{ 
      if(x.value == "volvo")
       {
       A.hidden=false;
          B.hidden=true; 
           C.hidden=true;
       }
     if(x.value == "saab")
     {  A.hidden=true;
          B.hidden=false; 
           C.hidden=true;

     }
     if(x.value == "opel")
         {
        A.hidden=true;
          B.hidden=true; 
           C.hidden=false;
         }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValue(ev)
{ 
var x=document.getElementById("sel");
var A=document.getElementById("a");
var B=document.getElementById("b");
  var C=document.getElementById("c");

  for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) 
  {
     if(x.options[i].selected ==true)
     {
       if(x.options[i].value == "volvo")
        {
         A.style.display = 'block';
         B.style.display = 'none';
         C.style.display = 'none';
       }
     if(x.options[i].value == "saab") //changed
     {   
         A.style.display = 'none'; //changed
         B.style.display = 'block';
         C.style.display = 'none';
     }
     if(x.options[i].value == "opel") //changed
         {
         A.style.display = 'none';
         B.style.display = 'none';
         C.style.display = 'block';
         }


       }
  }
}

var sel = document.getElementById('sel');

sel.addEventListener('change', getValue, false );
```

I changed the IF value names, since they were with the first letter in uppercase, the condition was always a no-match. :)

Also the second if was set to show the wrong div.

And third, use addEventListener to listen to change events on selects, don't use the onclick/onchange HTML thing.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enzoferber/wV2JD/)

Answer (score 0):

OK. Your JavaScript code is also a little messy. First off, you don't need to use a loop to get the job done. If you want to hide/display elements based on a certain selected option, first change the function to accept the value from the dropdown:

```
function getValue(selectedValue) {
    if (selectedValue == "volvo") {
        do something...
    }
    else if (selectedValue == "saab") {
        do something else...
    }
    else if (selectedValue == "Opel") {
        do something else...
    }
}
```

Then, the function call would be:

```
onChange="getValue(this.value)"
```